# Shutdown ExecutorService when no task has been submitted for a given time

Tags: java, executorservice, callable

I'm using an `ExecutorService` to call a service which basically connects to an application (local or remote via SSH), and allows to send commands to it and get its output.

So, the `Thread` created by the `ExecutorService` is waiting for user input, and this input is then processed as a task through an implementation of the call method, which returns the output and looks like this:

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    write(command);
    return readResult();
}
```

I would like to stop the `Thread` (shutdown the `ExecutorService`) when no task has been called for a given time, but I can't find how to do it... `Future.get` or `ExecutorService.invoke[All|Any]` can handle a timeout, but only regarding tasks it calls.

Any idea on how I could manage to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, whose doc says:

> Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources. Note that pools with similar properties but different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.

This shuts down the threads, not the entire executor, but that should be fine if the executor isn't actually taking any resources.

Comment: This seems to do the job! Now I have to call the application service shutdown method when the Thread shuts down, what I'll probably be able to do overriding `ExecutorService.shutdown()`.
Thanks for the quick n good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the implementation of the `Executors` class: The executors created, for example, with `newCachedThreadPool()` already have a timeout:

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
    60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

The timeout here is 60 seconds. If you want to construct an executor with a fixed pool size that times out, you additionally have to set `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor e = 
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
        keepAliveTime, timeUnit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
e.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

Comment: Having a look at the implementation of the `Executors` class has been my very first react reading @Louis answer!
+1 for the detailed suggestion :)